# Appium Android bootstrap socket crashed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: android, node.js, appium

### The problem

I have an already working appium tests suite on my MacOS desktop, but when i try to run the same tests on an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, I get the following error and appium gets closed automatically.

`Android bootstrap socket crashed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

Also, just to be clear, i'm not trying to run simultaneous tests, just a single emulated android device.

### Environment

- Appium version: `1.6.3-Beta`. Also tried with 1.5.3 and got the same error.
- Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): Not applicable.
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: `Ubuntu 16.04`
- Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe): `7.6.0`. But got the same error with v6.
- Mobile platform/version under test: `Andorid 6 (Marshmallow)`
- Real device or emulator/simulator: `Simulator`
- Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: `Appium CLI`

### Details

Been stuck on this for a few days. Saw some question referring to simultaneous tests on the internet, but its not my case. I'm trying to run my tests on a single emulated android device.

Also tried to change the bootstrap port using the `-bp` option, and set the localhost address using `-a 127.0.0.1`, but no success.

### Link to Appium logs

https://gist.github.com/BernalCarlos/752efe621a55a2b2b0d07b966c8b5354

Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by making a fresh install of linux mint 18.1.

Still don't know why this showed up in ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: i'm getting same error when i test with multiple android device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. Set `ADB` path in system variable as `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding the appium server argument --suppress-adb-kill-server, it prevents killing the adb server socket